# Custom Area in python

Tags: python, scripting

I guess every year or so there is someone asking the same question: How to create a custom area in python.

I need to create a Properties-like area for inputs to automate functions for fast renders. This is for non-3D users, so a very basic UI for specific purpose.

There is a custom node editor code online and conversations on creating new areas in C. But, within Python, is there way of creating a new editor with the Properties UI (buttons and panels and slides)

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: Hello ! The short answer is still no. I've seen some very hacky things done like in the Scatter 5 addon which monkeypatched an area in the preferences to display a custom interface, but it's not supported at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.